# Storing values from a nested loop in a matrix

Tags: r

I am trying to store values from a nested loop in a matrix. I've provided a simplified version of code below:

```
for (i in 1:2) {
  for (j in 1:2) {
    Test  <- i+j

    'Create Summary table of looping results'
    Summary_Loop <- matrix(ncol=2,nrow=2)
    Summary_Loop[i,j] <- Test

    'End of loop'
  }
}

Summary_Loop <- as.table(Summary_Loop)
print(Summary_Loop)
```

For some reason it is only storing the last value from the loop in the matrix. The entries [1,1] [1,2] and [2,1] are #N/A. Can anyone tell me how to get the matrix to store all values?

Comment: You seem to be re-making the matrix at ever iteration. Move the `Summary_Loop <- matrix(ncol=2,nrow=2)` line to before your `for` loops.

Comment: There is a simpler way to do this: `Mat <- matrix(NA, 2, 2)`; `Summary_Loop <- row(Mat) + col(Mat)`.

Comment: Thanks MrFlick, that solved the problem.